# How to use escape character in Label

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to use a label to contain this text :  Request Date/time

```
 <Label Text="Request Date/Time" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

The above markup not working for : / (date/time) , : (date:time)

Thanks

Comment: if you add a \ before /?

Comment: try this : <Label  FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold">Request Date/Time</Label?

Comment: I am using this :Label Text="Request Date/Time" , will try your approach and get back here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Weird, there should be no problem with that markup and a quick test indicates that I have no apparent errors when trying this. Since XAML is basically just XML, the only characters you need to escape are `<`, `>`, `&` and `"`. And they can be escaped by using their encoded counterpart (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&quot;`).

Do you get any error messages or what isn't working according to you?

As a workaround you could specify the text value like this: `<Label FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="Blue" FontAttributes="Bold">Request Date/Time</Label>`